# Replacing values in pandas dataframe using values in a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in my df which ends with ['-A','-B','-T','-Z','-EQ','-BE','-BL','-BT','-GC','-IL','-IQ'], and I need to remove the values.

I tried the below and got an error

```
df['name'] = df['name'].str.replace(['-A','-B','-T','-Z','-EQ','-BE','-BL','-BT','-GC','-IL','-IQ'],'', regex=True)
```

**TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) instead of  [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df['name'] = df['name'].replace(['-A','-B','-T','-Z','-EQ','-BE','-BL','-BT','-GC','-IL','-IQ'],'', regex=True)
```